# QGIS coordinates lost creating polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, latitude-longitude

New to QGIS, I'm facing the Problem that my lat, lon information has seemed to be lost creating polygons.

I created layers importing csv files being gps points. From these points I used the function points to line and then line to polygon which I saved as shapefile. It seems that now in my polygon there is no information about the latitude longitude anymore.

What can I do to retrieve the Information or how can I keep it during the process?

Comment: You can't keep it, at least not visible in the attribute table, since you're basically merging several features with different coordinates into on large feature. Still, since you are creating a spatial feature, the data is not lost but used to locate your feature. Why do you need the coordinates in the attribute table?

Comment: This video can be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZX5xhNVEyk

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I think the video is helpfull !

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates aren't lost, they're encoded within the .shx sidecar that makes up the shapefile.

Furthermore, it's only natural that GIS softwares won't retain lat/lon fields when converting from simpler to more complex geometries, as how exactly are you planning on retaining anywhere between 3 and several million sets of lat and lon values?

Lastly, If you still want to 'see' your coordinates, you can export your layer as a text based file, like GeoJSON or WKT, which exports lists of coordinate for each feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didnt know that the coordinates are encoded within. As I said I´m totally new to QGIS and it irritated me, the attribute table was empty. I dont need to see them, as long I now know they are still there :)